# Postgresql: How to delete rows from table constrained by date?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2, python-db-api

I am using psycopg2 and how can I delete rows that are older than a certain date? For example:

```
cursor.execute('DELETE FROM datatable WHERE date < %s', datetime.date(2012, 1, 1))
```

If I write like this, there will be TypeError: 'datetime.date' object does not support indexing. How can I do with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the second argument as a list or a tuple:

```
cursor.execute('DELETE FROM datatable WHERE date < %s', [datetime.date(2012, 1, 1)])
```